# Difference between Array and Vector

Tags: data-structures, julia

Is there a difference between `Array` and `Vector`?

```
typeof(Array([1,2,3]))
Vector{Int64}

typeof(Vector([1,2,3]))
Vector{Int64}
```

Both seem to create the same thing, but they are not the same:

```
Array == Vector
false

Array === Vector
false
```

So, what is actually the difference?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The difference is that `Vector` is a 1-dimensional `Array`, so when you write e.g. `Vector{Int}` it is a shorthand to `Array{Int, 1}`:

```
julia> Vector{Int}
Array{Int64,1}
```

When you call constructors `Array([1,2,3])` and `Vector([1,2,3])` they internally get translated to the same call `Array{Int,1}([1,2,3])` as you passed a vector to them.

You would see the difference if you wanted to pass an array that is not 1-dimensional:

```
julia> Array(ones(2,2))
2×2 Array{Float64,2}:
 1.0  1.0
 1.0  1.0

julia> Vector(ones(2,2))
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching Array{T,1} where T(::Array{Float64,2})
```

Also note the effect of:

```
julia> x=[1,2,3]
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3

julia> Vector(x)
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3

julia> Vector(x) === x
false
```

So essentially the call `Vector(x)` makes a copy of `x`. Usually in the code you would probably simply write `copy(x)`.

A general rule is that `Array` is a parametric type that has two parameters given in curly braces:

- the first one is element type (you can access it using `eltype`)
- the second one is the dimension of the array (you can access it using `ndims`)

See https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/arrays/ for details.

Answer (score 10):

`Vector` is an alias for a one-dimensional `Array`.  You can see that in the Julia REPL:

```
julia> Vector
Array{T, 1} where T

julia> Vector{Int32}
Array{Int32, 1}
```

Similarly, a `Matrix` is a 2-dimensional Array:

```
julia> Matrix
Array{T,2} where T
```