# Get Type in Array

Tags: julia

How can I get the type inside an array?

```
a = [1,2,3]
```

I can get the type of `a`

```
typeof(a)
Vector{Int64}
```

but I actually want `Int64`. First, I thought a newbie work-around could be

```
typeof(a[1])
Int64
```

but this is actually not correct, as can be seen here:

```
a = [1,2,3, missing]

typeof(a)
Vector{Union{Missing, Int64}}
```

The type of the vector is `Union{Missing, Int64}`, but the type of the first element is

```
typeof(a[1])
Int64
```

So, how do I get the type of the vector/array?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the `eltype` function:

```
julia> a = [1,2,3]
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3

julia> eltype(a)
Int64

julia> a = [1,2,3, missing]
e4-element Array{Union{Missing, Int64},1}:
 1
 2
 3
  missing

julia> eltype(a)
Union{Missing, Int64}
```

Comment: I the other answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61171531/difference-between-array-and-vector I have expanded on the logic of both arguments of the parametric type `Array`.